# C# - Identify variable usage in source code

Tags: c#, .net, metaprogramming

I'm currently looking for a library that can find parts of code where variables are used and replace them with some other code.

For example in this code:

```
int foo = 0;
int a = foo * 5;
```

the library could identify foo so that I could replace it with this:

```
int foo = 0;
int a = DoSomething(foo) * 5;
```

Does anything similar exist?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I don't know the name of these variables. I have to identify them as such and then replace the code. For example, I need to find out if *foo* is a variable and not a method/comment/anything else and then replace it.

Comment: You're looking for Roslyn.

Comment: could you not write one? sounds like a pretty simple text parser where you just use find the string and replace it.

Comment: At runtime or at code time? if it's at code time just use the replace utility of visual studio.

Comment: @Jacobr365: No; what about strings or comments?

Comment: @Slaks What? It looks like they want to search a file (like a .cs file) and modify the code in it. Searching a file for "// _something_" is not hard or just take in a string of what you want to search for...

Comment: @Jacobr365 You underestimate the complexity of building a static analyzer...

Comment: Just do a find and replace?

Comment: @DStanley Maybe, but from his question it is not really analyzing anything, just searching for a given string and replacing it with another.

Comment: You can also refractor and find, not only replace (with VS)

Comment: @SLaks I've heard about Roslyn, but I don't know how it could help me.

Comment: @Jacobr365 Sorry for my poor explanation. My aim is to identify variables without knowing their name.

Comment: @samuelemarro: You can use Roslyn to parse and rewrite the syntax tree.

Comment: @SLaks Is there a free and/or good guide for Roslyn you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you want to do this, maybe instead of changing the code where `foo` is used you could change its definition:

```
int foo = 0;
int a = foo * 5;
```

becomes something like

```
int _foo = 0;
int foo
{
    get
    {
        return DoSomething(_foo);
    }
}
int a = foo * 5;
```

Comment: If it's C#6 you could use an expression: `int foo => DoSomething(_foo);`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the library you are trying to use is obfuscated. It wont be as simle to replace the string. There may be some tool to undo dotfuscation. I am not aware of any but searching might land you somewhere.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that this has to do with obfuscation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not doing anything related to obfuscation. Sorry for my poor explanation.